# Как изменить главный файл темы wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

У меня стоит стандартная тема Twenty Twenty Two, но если я поменяю файл home.html на home.php, тогда он не будет видеть его при заходе на сайт, в какой настройке мне нужно поменять название файла или что нужно сделать?

Искал в "Страницы", но там нет главной страницы

Comment: Потому что там не просто так html файл и все же нужно знать чуть больше чем ничего, прежде чем лезть что-то делать. Начать стоило бы с создания дочерней темы. Какова Ваша конечная цель?